# Entity Framework 4: Mapped Stored Procedure on Model with Additional Parameters

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We've started using Entity Framework 4 for data access and have come across an issue or perhaps lack of understanding.

Our current system is heavily reliant on Stored Procedures, these procedure contain some necessary business logic so we need to continue to use these when doing Select/Insert/Update/Delete.

The issue we are having is the following:

We've mapped a table to an entity, let's say for example this is a User entity and has the following properties - UserId, FirstName, LastName

Now in our sproc to insert a user we accept FirstName, LastName, CreatedById as parameters.

As our User Entity has no CreatedById we get an error indicating that no property of our Entity can be mapped to the "CreatedById" parameter.

Now one thing we've tried is to manually add a CreatedById scalar property to our Entity, but this results in the issue that there is no Field in our User table in the data source that maps to CreatedById. In general the additional property that we'd like to pass in is not something that is stored.

Now there is potential solution to this in that we can just map the procedures to Function Imports and not bother with using the .AddObject, .DeleteObject, .SaveChanges way of manipulating our objects but that doesn't feel like the way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

that's a good question. There are few options i can tell u.
instead of mapping the entity to the table, map it a view and have the view return CreatedById and then your problem would be solved.

Second option is to create overloaded stored procedure that takes only FirstName, LastName and calls the actual stored procedure with a default value for CreatedById. You can create overloads at the database layer or create it in the model in the ssdl layer which supports inline stored procedure.

exec myproc @firstName,@LastName,null

Comment: Thanks for your response unfortunately that won't solve our problem, the procedure we are calling already sets a default value for the additional parameter. The parameter we are trying to pass in has no representation in the DB so a view won't work either.

Perhaps CreatedById was a bad example in this case. The parameter in question is basically just used to indicate how the other data should be handled. Another example might be if the param is "Source" which indicates where the request to create the user came from, this then effects how we store the user or maybe how we set UserType.